# How to edit and refresh a locally opened html using python script?

Tags: python, html

Using python program a local html file is opened in browser,there is a table   in the html file,I want to **edit** the content of a cell in the table.
Also I want to **refresh** it using python,since the .html file is updated.

Comment: " editing a cell"  can be done, like any edit can be done, but this is really too little information. Also, refreshing a page is specific to the browser (and depends on if it is possible at all from the command line).

Comment: @Jacob :to keep my question simple ,I just want to edit a opened html file and refresh that html file using python only.